# What's typical in terms of reliability for fully wired Ethernet LAN for normal, non-outage, non-overload conditions?

Tags: load-balancing, local-area-network, ethernet

Can anyone point me to industry guidance of any kind for expected LAN reliability for normal, non-outage, non-overload conditions? I suspect some device is blocking or throttling my connections. I have some code that connects to another service in the same data center thru a hardware load-balancer. In my testing, one out of 40,000 connections fails to connect. I've gotten a suggestion that one out of a billion connection failures, is more reasonable. I understand TCP/IP has some fault tolerance for physical/electrical issues. So, maybe 100% reliability should actually be expected under normal conditions. Again, I’m supposing that no overloading is happening.

I used the below PowerShell command to isolate the issue from the complexities of my code and from IIS on the servers. This command does a simple TCP connection test to port 443 without trying to establish any HTTP/HTTPS connection, just basic TCP. It's doing 50 connections sequentially and pausing for 10 seconds. I may try doing them evenly spaced to see if there’s some low throttling/DOS prevention being activated by the burst of 50 sequential connections. Any other suggestions are welcome, but my main goal here is to get authoritative numbers. Any networking professional’s opinion of sensible numbers is also welcome.

```
1..120000 | % {1..50 | % {$result=Test-NetConnection example.local -Port 443 -InformationLevel Detailed; if(-not $result.TcpTestSucceeded) {Get-Date >>e:\testnettranscript.txt; $result | Select-Object * >>e:\testnettranscript.txt}}; Start-Sleep 10}
```

Answer (score 2):

Reliability is never 100%.

Typical bit error rates are irrelevant if you have not searched for faults in this network. A spec may say 1 error bit in however many billion, but that doesn't prevent your hardware from being faulty or your software buggy.

- Review error logs and resource utilization of the web server.
- Identify all firewalls, proxies, and other middleboxes in the path and what they might be doing to flows.
- Check all interfaces on the path for errors and replace faulty components.
- Do a packet capture and see if the errors are in Ethernet frames or in the TCP/IP stack.
- Send test UDP datagrams to check if the problem is isolated to TCP or not.

Comment: Thanks. It's possible that industry guidance is hard to find, but I'd still like to know typical or recommended TCP connection failure rates. If my error rate was one in 50 trillion connections, I suppose people would say that I should go find a hammock and enjoy my life. I'm not particularly concerned with the lower level bit error rates, just TCP connections. As I understand, TCP/IP has some ability to recover some bit error issues. So, that would all be opaque.

Comment: There isn't a spec for TCP failure rates like there is for a single Ethernet PHY. That flow can cross many links, routers, and middleboxes, making failure analysis complex. IP, especially over Ethernet, is unreliable. If you don't like your failure rates, find the faults in your network.

Comment: What minimal level of reliability would you expect for fully wired Ethernet LAN for normal, non-outage, non-overload conditions? Would you go looking for faults for one failed connection in every million? I need consensus estimates for what's bad since I can't investigate everything on my network myself and other administrators here are not concerned with the TCP failures and the application failures they cause since I clean up the application failures manually.